# Bash /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward: Permission denied

Tags: command-line, bash

I tried to run

```
echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
```

It says Access denied from bash, I then did:

```
sudo chmod 1+x /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
```

and now it says Operation not permitted.

How can I gain access?

Comment: Try this: `echo 1 | sudo tee /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward`

Comment: That worked, can you explain what tee does?

Comment: The problem with `sudo echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward` is that the redirection of the output is done not as `sudo`, so it doesn't work. From the man page: `tee - read from standard input and write to standard output and files`, and if done as `sudo` it does have sufficient privileges to write to the file.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The permission bits for the file `/proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward` is:

```
-rw-r--r--
```

with `owner:group` being `root:root`.

So only `root` can write to the file.

When you do:

```
echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
```

as a normal user, you won't be able to write to the file due to insufficient permission.

You can do:

- Use `sudo` and `bash`:

  ```
  sudo bash -c 'echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward'
  ```
- Use `tee`:

  ```
  echo 1 | sudo tee /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
  ```

---

Note that, you should use `/etc/sysctl.conf` for persistent operations on the `/proc/sys` subdirectories.

In a nutshell, to enable IP forwarding, you can just put the following in `/etc/sysctl.conf`:

```
net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1
```

Then run:

```
sudo sysctl -p
```

to have immediate effect.

This has the same effect as editing the file `/proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward`  directly, and not to mention far cleaner and of course persistent.

Comment: Doing echo 1 | sudo tee /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward worked for me, can you explain what tee is?

Comment: @ChrisEthanFox `tee` is command to send whatever it receives to both on the standard output and to files. Check `man tee`

Comment: I'm logged in as root but still can not use rm command (`rm /proc/sys/net/ipv4/icmp_echo_ignore_all`) to remove such file! I even checked immutable bit and its not set on that file... I get the same error "rm: cannot remove ‘/proc/sys/net/ipv4/icmp_echo_ignore_all’: Permission denied". But magically i can edit file as you described! I can't realize whats the problem with `rm`!

Comment: @MojtabaRezaeian It's the kernel that's preventing the removal. `/proc` i.e. `procfs` lives on the memory and is exposed by the kernel. So you're getting a view of the kernel, and whatever kernel allows you to do to the files on such a FS is totally upto the kernel.

Comment: @heemayl So how can I remove that file because creating that file was an option to permanently disable icmp ping requests to my server but after creating that file now i changed my mind but there is no way to remove that option(although now its not option when it can not be changed!) do you have any idea how to do that? or maybe it requires to open another question?

Comment: @heemayl I have asked my question on a new thread here: [rm /proc/sys/net/ipv4/icmp_echo_ignore_all](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/548389/bash-rm-proc-sys-net-ipv4-icmp-echo-ignore-all-permission-denied)

Answer (score 1):

A simpler solution is using:

```
sudo su
```

by this call you will login to your root user and you will be able to edit the file.

N.B: use this at your own risk.