# bash: proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_foward no such file or directory found

Tags: command-line, bash, ip-forward

If I try to run echo 1 > proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_foward

It gives me this bash: proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_foward no such file or directory found

I tried to do sudo echo 1 > and, echo 1 | sudo tee with the command with no success

Comment: You should not write anything to the /proc/sys folders - it's a read-only folder for the system.

Answer (score 3):

You need to start from the root: `/`

```
echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
```

Let me add that what you are trying to accomplish would be more practical with:

```
sysctl net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
```

With this command you don't need to be root, and you can just use `sudo`. 
Remember that either way these are not persistent.

Check this [Answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/783017/bash-proc-sys-net-ipv4-ip-forward-permission-denied?rq=1) as well.